# Passing locales to javascript partial in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have a partial that contains javascript

```
#shared/monkey.js
:javascript
  //javascript code here
```

and I want to be able to use partial in that

```
render :partial => 'shared/monkey', :locals => {:monkey => 'HELLO'}
```

how do i use the variable monkey inside my partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, found out a way.

in order to execute ruby code in your :javascript block, you need to do

```
"#{ruby_code}"
```